# How to extract year, month, day, hour and minutes from a DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-datetime

I would like to know how to extract the year, month, day, hour and minutes from a `DateTimeField`?

The DateTimeField I want to extract the info is called 'redemption_date' and the code for the model is this:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   class Code(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        code_key = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
        redemption_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
        
        # ...
        def is_expired(self):
            expired_date = datetime.now() - timedelta( days=2 )
            my_redemtion_date = self.redemption_date
            if self.redemption_date is None:
                return False
            if my_redemtion_date  < expired_date:
                    return True
            else:
                return False
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[From the datetime documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) :

```
[...]
class datetime.datetime
A combination of a date and a time. Attributes: year, month, day, hour, 
minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo.
[...]
```

So you can extract your wanted information by directly accessing the `redemption_date`'s attributes.

Comment: This is confusing without examples.

Answer (score 7):

```
redemption_date.year
redemption_date.month
etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that your first source of information should be python itself. You can just type in your shell, after importing datetime:

```
dir(datetime)
# even more detail on
help(datetime)
```